# YouTube embed not responsive with bootstrap

Tags: video, bootstrap-4, youtube, embed, bootstrap-5

I have a couple of videos I would like to put on my website but there are some issues:

- The videos are not responsive
- The aspect ratio of the videos seems to be fixed

I have been crawling through the stackoverflow and other websites and tried all sorts of solutions but i cant seem to resolve any of these problems. I even copy and pasted the code outside of any containers/tables and it was still the same thing.

Here is my code with the embeds inside a table and I would like the videos to look like *https://codepen.io/ondrejsvestka/pen/dWYdBK* with the 16:9 aspect ratio with 2 embeds next to each other. I added a video with 9by16 just to show that it doesnt work regardless of the ratios I include.

```
    <td>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-9by16">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CrZtQrvKHjU" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div></td>
    <td>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3yL7a4jJ62I" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
```

And the CSS

```
.table{
width:50% !important;
table-layout: fixed;
margin:0px auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 20px 25px;
}

th, td{
background-color:#f7f7f7 !important;
padding:20px !important;
border-radius:10px;
border:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: For me your code works as expected.

Comment: Thats odd, then im not understanding what the problem is at all.

Comment: You need to show a more complete example of the `<table>`. Is this the first `<tr>`?